# Drawing multiple rectangle using DrawRect efficiently

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, drawrect, cgcontext

I'm trying to draw rectangles pattern using DrawRect like this:

[image]

Currently, I'm doing this like so:

```
class PatternView: UIView {
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        
        let numberOfBoxesPerRow = 7
        let boxSide: CGFloat = rect.width / CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow)
        var yOrigin: CGFloat = 0
        var xOrigin: CGFloat = 0
        var isBlack = true
        
        for y in 0...numberOfBoxesPerRow - 1 {
            yOrigin = boxSide * CGFloat(y)
            for x in 0...numberOfBoxesPerRow - 1 {

                xOrigin = boxSide * CGFloat(x)
                let color = isBlack ? UIColor.red : UIColor.blue
                isBlack = !isBlack

                context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
                
                let rectnagle =  CGRect(origin: .init(x: xOrigin, y: yOrigin), size: .init(width: boxSide, height: boxSide))
                context?.addRect(rectnagle)
                context?.fill([rectnagle])
            }
        }
           
    }
}
```

**It's working but I'm trying to optimize it.

Any help will be highly appreciated!**

Comment: How frequently is the drawing done? Have you profiled it (e.g. with Instruments)? Is the drawing method a bottleneck for the performance of your application?

Comment: Hey @MartinR! How are you? In my specific scenario, it's not the worse. I haven't profiled it but from past experience, CGContext is highly configurable and I was wondering about a better way to implement it. I just did a raw implementation to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Also, @MartinR, I just used white and gray colors for the boxes and seems like it's not smooth (the outline between the white and gray is not smooth)

Comment: @MartinR https://ibb.co/Qp7n5Lp

Comment: Add  a `print("drawRect")` statement to the drawing method when you run the program from Xcode. How often is it called?

Comment: For the “not so smooth” problem, try `let rectnagle = CGRect(...).integral`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to answer "abstract" questions... which this one is, without knowing if you've run some tests / profiling to determine if this code is slow.

However, a couple things you *can* do to speed it up...

- fill the view with one color (red, in this case) and then draw only the other-color boxes
- add rects to the context's path, and fill the path once

Take a look at this modification:

```
class PatternView: UIView {
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        let numberOfBoxesPerRow = 7
        let boxSide: CGFloat = rect.width / CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow)
        
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.fill(bounds)
        
        var r: CGRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: boxSide, height: boxSide))
        
        context.beginPath()
        
        for row in 0..<numberOfBoxesPerRow {
            r.origin.x = 0.0
            for col in 0..<numberOfBoxesPerRow {
                if (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 1) || (row % 2 == 1 && col % 2 == 0) {
                    context.addRect(r)
                }
                r.origin.x += boxSide
            }
            r.origin.y += boxSide
        }
        
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        
        context.fillPath()

    }
}
```

There are other options... create a "pattern" background color... use `CAShapeLayer`s and/or `CAReplicatorLayer`s... for example.

---

**Edit**

The reason you are getting "blurry edges" is because, as you guessed, you're drawing on partial pixels.

If we modify the values to use **whole numbers** (using `floor()`), we can avoid that. Note that the wholeNumberBoxSide * numBoxes may then NOT be exactly equal to the view's rect, so we'll also want to inset the "grid":

```
class PatternView: UIView {
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        let c1: UIColor = .white
        let c2: UIColor = .lightGray
        
        let numberOfBoxesPerRow = 7
        
        // use a whole number
        let boxSide: CGFloat = floor(rect.width / CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow))

        // inset because numBoxes * boxSide may not be exactly equal to rect
        let inset: CGFloat = floor((rect.width - boxSide * CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow)) * 0.5)
        
        context.setFillColor(c1.cgColor)
        context.fill(CGRect(x: inset, y: inset, width: boxSide * CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow), height: boxSide * CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow)))
        
        var r: CGRect = CGRect(x: inset, y: inset, width: boxSide, height: boxSide)
        
        context.beginPath()
        
        for row in 0..<numberOfBoxesPerRow {
            r.origin.x = inset
            for col in 0..<numberOfBoxesPerRow {
                if (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 1) || (row % 2 == 1 && col % 2 == 0) {
                    context.addRect(r)
                }
                r.origin.x += boxSide
            }
            r.origin.y += boxSide
        }
        
        context.setFillColor(c2.cgColor)
        
        context.fillPath()

    }
}
```

We ***could*** also get the scale of the main screen (which will be 2x or 3x) and round the boxSide to half- or one-third points to align with the pixels... if really desired.

---

**Edit 2**

Additional modifications... settable colors and number of boxes.

Also, using this extension:

```
// extension to round CGFloat values to floor/nearest CGFloat
//  so, for example
//  if f == 10.6
//      f.floor(nearest: 0.5)    = 10.5
//      f.floor(nearest: 0.3333) = 10.3333
//      f.round(nearest: 0.5)    = 10.5
//      f.round(nearest: 0.3333) = 10.66666
extension CGFloat {
    func round(nearest: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let n = 1/nearest
        let numberToRound = self * n
        return numberToRound.rounded() / n
    }
    
    func floor(nearest: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let intDiv = CGFloat(Int(self / nearest))
        return intDiv * nearest
    }
}
```

We can round the coordinates to match the screen scale.

**PatternView class**

```
class PatternView: UIView {

    var c1: UIColor = .white { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    var c2: UIColor = .lightGray { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    var numberOfBoxesPerRow = 21 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        let sc: CGFloat = 1.0 // / CGFloat(UIScreen.main.scale)
        
        // use a whole number
        let boxSide: CGFloat = (rect.width / CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow)).floor(nearest: sc)
        
        // inset because numBoxes * boxSide may not be exactly equal to rect
        let inset: CGFloat = ((rect.width - boxSide * CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow)) * 0.5).floor(nearest: sc)
        
        context.setFillColor(c1.cgColor)
        context.fill(CGRect(x: inset, y: inset, width: boxSide * CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow), height: boxSide * CGFloat(numberOfBoxesPerRow)))
        
        var r: CGRect = CGRect(x: inset, y: inset, width: boxSide, height: boxSide)
        
        context.beginPath()
        
        for row in 0..<numberOfBoxesPerRow {
            r.origin.x = inset
            for col in 0..<numberOfBoxesPerRow {
                if (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 1) || (row % 2 == 1 && col % 2 == 0) {
                    context.addRect(r)
                }
                r.origin.x += boxSide
            }
            r.origin.y += boxSide
        }
        
        context.setFillColor(c2.cgColor)
        
        context.fillPath()
        
    }
}
```

**Example Controller View class**

```
class PatternTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let pvA = PatternView()
    let pvB = PatternView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 8
        
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        [pvA, pvB].forEach { v in
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            v.numberOfBoxesPerRow = 7
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        pvB.numberOfBoxesPerRow += 1
    }
}
```

Sets up two pattern views... both start at 7 boxes... each tap anywhere increments the boxes per row in the bottom view.

Here's how it looks with 21 boxes per row (actual size - so really big image):

[image]

and zoomed-in 1600%:

[image]

Note the red borders... I set the background of the view to red, so we can see that the grid must be inset to account for the non-whole-number box size.

---

**Edit 3**

Options to avoid "blurry edges" ...

Suppose we have a view width of `209` and we want `10` boxes.

That gives us a box width of 20.9 ... which results in "blurry edges" -- so we know we need to get to a whole number.

If we **round** it, we'll get `21` -- `21 x 10 = 210` which will exceed the width of the view. So we need to round it down (`floor()`).

So...

[image]

Option 1:

[image]

Option 2:

[image]

Option 3:

[image]

Comment: Hey @DongMag, I agree that it is abstract question but you already improved it :) Similiar to what Pierre wrote this does work. But the issue with the blurry lines remains (a bit better than my approach but still visible). Something with half pixels IMO, but not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Example: https://ibb.co/VvPzWds

Comment: @RoiMulia - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Hey DonMag! We are really getting there, I ran the app and it's crispy clear lines, but you are correct with the inset of the grid. If I'm increasing the numberOfBoxesPerRow to 21 for example, it's getting really bad. Is it possible to keep the crystal clear lines and fill the grid as expected? Appreciate your help DongMag! Example: https://ibb.co/jV6Jg2v

Comment: As I mentioned above, the  to-be-drawn rectangle should be set to integral coordinates with `context.addRect(r.integral)`

Comment: @RoiMulia - are you doing something like generating an image and then scaling it?

Comment: @DonMag no, I just create the UIView and added it to the hierarchy (as is). It is always a square

Comment: @MartinR I tried doing it but it looks the same, maybe I'm .integral the wrong part? I did it to all of the rectangles in the code and also tried only on the context one

Comment: @RoiMulia - really not sure what you've done different. See my **Edit 2** -- with a `CGFloat` extension for floor / rounding; an updated `PatternView` class; and an example view controller.

Comment: Hey @DonMag, first of all, I'm always amazed by how deep an answer can go even for simple subjects like this. Thank you so much! It's working. I had an idea of how to fix the inset issue. Let's say we want an estimated 10 boxes per row. We can run calculations (depending on the rect) and get the closest upper/downer number of numberOfBoxes that will fill the entire rectangle. What do you think?

Comment: I just tapped a few times on the view and in some scenarios it filled up perfectly.

Comment: @RoiMulia - see my **Edit 3** ...

Answer (score 1):

I think your first move would be to first draw a big red square, then to draw only the blue ones on top of it. It would spare half the computations, even if it does not change the order of magnitude.

**EDIT**

Note : it is always the drawing itself that consumes time, rarely the other computations. So that is what we have to minimize.

So, my second move would be to replace drawing squares by creating just one complicated BezierPath, that makes all the squares into just one form, and then display it only once.
I do not know if it is possible to do the whole in just one form, but it is possible to make two columns of blue squares into one form.

**EDIT 2**

Also, I do not understant why there are two instructions here :

```swift
context?.addRect(rectnagle)
context?.fill([rectnagle])
```

Shouldn't only the second be enough ?

Comment: Hey @Pierre. That's a good idea! Do you have any idea about the blurry lines? (you can check the latest image in my comment)

Comment: Hello ! I have added some more thoughts. Maybe my second edit will correct the blurry lines. If not, you might have to review the computations to check that nothing is drawn superimposed.

Comment: Hey Pierre! That was a good suggestion, @DonMag implement it but the blurry lines are still there :/ Any idea?

Comment: Yes, I finally guessed it was about non-integer pixel values, but @DonMag already answered that.